# Problem with call windows API inline assembly

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly, call, inline-assembly

I want to anti-debug and write a function like following code to call API debug "IsDebuggerPresent" to check:

```
#include "windows.h"
bool checkdbg(){
    int i = 1;
    __asm{
        call IsDebuggerPresent //gọi api debug
        test eax, eax
        jne L1
        mov i,0
        L1 : 
    }
    if(i == 0) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

But when compile,VS2010 can not find `IsDebuggerPresent` to call.Please help me !

Comment: What is the exact error the compiler gives you?

Comment: Why the assembler? Any reason not to add a reference to `kernel32.lib` and simply call `IsDebuggerPresent`?

Comment: Since he's including Windows.h, it's not necessary to add any further reference at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "Windows.h"

bool checkdbg() {
    __asm {
        call IsDebuggerPresent //gọi api debug
        test eax, eax
        jne L1
        mov i,0
        L1 : 
    }
    if(i == 0) return false;
    else return true;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow ) {
  checkdbg();
  return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

This will compile just fine. It's probably complaining because you were missing an entry point. The subsystem you supplied in the project options mandates what main is required, whether that be WinMain (for Windows subsystem) or main (for console subsystem).

Also I would advise using:

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

As opposed to:

```
#include "Windows.h"
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) for explanation. Also you should just do this:

```
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL checkdbg() {
    int i = 1;
    __asm{
        call IsDebuggerPresent
        ret
    }
}

int main() {
  checkdbg();
  return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

The return is expected in eax anyway so you may as well return, otherwise all you're doing is checking if the return is true, then return true. If it's false, return false. Just return. The only thing you did was effectively cast from BOOL to bool. Beats me why you're using inline ASM for this anyway though.

Comment: No,I just give my function.I have main function(sure).But I can not call  IsDebuggerPresent API.So,when I try your code,it can not retn because compiler can't call IsDebuggerPresent.

Comment: his error is : "Unhandled exception at 0x00d581e0 in antidebug.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation".When i disassembly to debug on VS2010,at line "call IsDebuggerPresent",compiler can not call ..

Comment: an unhandled exception is a runtime error, and has nothing to do with the compiler...

Comment: Oh. I don't know why VC++ does this. I encountered this before debugging into inline assembler code. Perhaps a bug?

Comment: after testing both code: i get an unhandled in both cases, looks like something is not setup appropriately before calling the function. calling the C API works well... (i told you, inline assembler is a maintenance nightmare)

Comment: Thank all.I have a another question.If you re free,reference into this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270687/how-to-get-parent-process-id-throught-teb-or-peb

Answer (score 0):

any reason for not calling the API directly from C ?

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")

bool checkdbg() {
    return IsDebuggerPresent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but i want to inline ASM,not use call API from C like this.
the ways of Mike Kwan cant run successfully because compiler not call IsDebuggerPresent.So,it cant return(on eax register)

Comment: so your problem is when compiling. someone asked you: what is the exact error message the compiler gives you ? what is the result of the compilation ? the error message is crucial in understanding why the compiler fails...

Comment: (also, note that inlining assembler does not add anything, except some maintenance nightmares)

Comment: This error is : "Unhandled exception at 0x00d581e0 in antidebug.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation".When i disassembly to debug on VS2010,at line "call IsDebuggerPresent",compiler can not call ..

Answer (score 0):

do not use

```
call balabala
```

use

```
call dword ptr [balabala]
```